# Excel VBA Warning Before Adding New Row/Column if Cell is Already Copied in Clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

You know how sometimes you copy a cell in Excel, and then forget you copied it, and try to insert a new column/row, and you end up pasting the value from that cell over the entire new column/row? If you do, you know that this is super annoying!!! Especially when dealing with a big file or if the copied cell has a formula since it has crashed my excel many times.

Anyone have an idea of how to write a macro that warns before adding a new row/column if a cell is already copied into clipboard (i.e., would paste that cell's content in all cells of new column/row)?

Comment: I'm sure it's *poosible*, but that doesn't make it easy.  There isn't an event that would get you anywhere near knowing if a row was about to be inserted.  You'd likely have to hook the Excel menus. Compared to that, examining the clipboard state isn't nearly as difficult.

Comment: I'm sure it'll involve using `Application.CutCopyMode <> False`. The event is the question.

Comment: Obviously Ctrl+Z gets us there 90% of the time... the bigger issue is when dealing with a massive spreadsheet with 20k+ rows, copying a lookup formula cell, and then adding a new row => Crashed Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as a VBA solutions is concerned, below is a worksheet event.

It will not message the user before you paste what is in your Excel clipboard but will do so if you're about to select multiple rows/columns/cells. From a user experience standpoint, this is likely good enough.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Application.CutCopyMode <> False And Target.Cells.Count > 5000 Then
        MsgBox "Excel is in cut/copy mode..."
    End If
End Sub
```

This would need to go into each worksheet you want the warning to occur.

EDIT: OR! Use the below in ThisWorkBook

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Application.CutCopyMode <> False And Target.Cells.Count > 5000 Then
        MsgBox "Excel is in cut/copy mode..."
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT2: The above only works on the active workbook. For using it in a personal workbook, Pearson did a good job of explaining how something like this could work for all workbooks (even non macro files), [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx).
The big change I expect is when they explain the below. I can't test it right now, but I expect Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(...) to be the thing to make it work.

```
Private XLApp As CExcelEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     Set XLApp = New CExcelEvents
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great - Thanks! but does not seem to work in "personal" thisworkbook, only individual files - is there a way to get it to work in "personal" so it would apply to every file?

Comment: It is possible to get events to pass from individual workbooks to personal.xlsm. Don't have the code off hand (at work). I'll add a link which can help explain how it'd work if I find it. Adding the link to Answer.